# SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE statement on Stored Procedure in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, prepared-statement

I need export one MySQL table in .csv format.

To do this I have tried this **Stored Procedure** using the **SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE** statement is intended to enable dumping a table to a csv file on the server host.

But I receive thsi error :

> Procedure execution failed 1064 - You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
>   for the right syntax to use near 'C:\inetpub\ftproot\tm_20200322.csv'
>   at line 1

Can you help me ?

My code below.

```
BEGIN

  SET @tbl = DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY), '%Y%m%d');
  SET @s = CONCAT('C:\\inetpub\\ftproot\\\tm_', @tbl, '.csv');
  PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
  EXECUTE stmt;

  SET @s = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM `dotable` INTO OUTFILE @s FIELDS TERMINATED BY ";" LINES TERMINATED BY "\n"');
  PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
  EXECUTE stmt;

END
```

Comment: Why are you preparing `@s` and then attempting to execute it, its an output file path isnt it

Comment: Oh and then you overwrite it ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file name must be enclosed with single quotes. Also, it is unclear why you would need to execute twice. You also need to carefuly use the escaping `\` (there are places where you have one to many, others where one is mising).

This should do what you want:

```
SET @tbl = DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY), '%Y%m%d');
SET @s = CONCAT('C:\\inetpub\\ftproot\\tm_', @tbl, '.csv');
SET @s = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM `dotable` INTO OUTFILE ''', @s, ''' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ";" LINES TERMINATED BY "\\n"');
PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

This code [generates the following query](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=71b7c711fe651a233589931e41e82abf):

```
SELECT * FROM `dotable` INTO OUTFILE 'C:\inetpub\ftproot\tm_20200322.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ";" LINES TERMINATED BY "\n"
```

Comment: Am I right about the first prepare being nonsense? Its a file path isnt it

Comment: Oh and this is not the statement that is generating the error the OP is asking about

Comment: @RiggsFolly: yes. I reviewed more thoroughly and updated my answer (and tested it!).